# How To Use ImageTool Component for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, components

I'm working on a CakePHP project where I need to apply some image transformations. I chose to try this one: https://github.com/raitisg/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component. However, I can't seem to figure out how to use it even by the examples given on the github-page like this one:

```
$status = ImageTool::resize(array(
    'input' => $input_file,
    'output' => $output_file,
    'width' => 600,
    'height' => 600,
    'keepRatio' => true,
    'paddings' => false,
    'afterCallbacks' => array(
        array('watermark', array('watermark' => $watermark_file, 'position' => 'bottom-right')),
        array('unsharpMask'),
    )
));
```

I want to use ImageTool in a Controller where I run through a directory with images that shall get transformed and copied to another directory (and their paths into a database). I know the above example is a static call, but what does $status mean here? Where am I supposed to set $input_file, $output_file and $watermark_file?

I found ImageTool referenced on the CakePHP site, but couldn't find any real life examples.

Comment: This has zero tests and looks pretty basic. Try Imagine directly or try the Imagine plugin https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin for CakePHP. It's a very nice OOP lib for image manipulation.

Comment: @burzum, thanks for your quick answer. I totally agree that ImageTool looks very basic where I do need a more robust solution. I followed your advice and took a look at _Imagine_ and was able to make cropped images within minutes. However, applying watermarks like described in the Quickstart section failed and I don't know how to fix this. I took a quick look at your plugin; is there a more detailed documentation available? Yes, I'm a noob ;-) For now I will start a new question regarding _Imagine_ watermarks to avoid cluttering this topic.

Comment: Take a look at the behavior methods of the plugin. It basically is a wrapper around most imagine methods and it also provides an instance of the imagine object. Watermarks are explained with an example in the imagine documentation itself. https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/introduction.html#image-watermarking

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your component to the `$component` property of the controller. Also you can take a look inside of `$status` via `debug()`.

Try this:

```
<?php
class TestController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('ImageTool');

    public function index() {
        $status = $this->ImageTool->resize(array(
            'input' => 'my-original-photo.jpg',
            'output' => 'my-resized-photo.jpg',
            'width' => 600,
            'height' => 600,
            'keepRatio' => true,
            'paddings' => false,
            'afterCallbacks' => array(
                array('watermark', array('watermark' => 'watermark.jpg', 'position' => 'bottom-right')),
                array('unsharpMask'),
            )
        ));

        debug($status);

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I was able to successfully apply a watermark! However, there were some issues:

Comment: thank you very much - I was able to successfully apply a watermark using ImageTool! However, there were some issues: having it as a $components threw a CakeError. I simply used App::import('Vendor', 'ImageTool') as you stated, having the script in the app/Vendor (no subfolder) folder. Next thing: above code `$this->ImageTool->resize()` seems to provoke an error, too. After looking into the ImageTool Class (and documentation on github) I used `ImageTool::watermark()`. Works fine. Am I still missing something?

Comment: I don't get it which code "above" `$this->ImageTool->resize()` provokes an error, too. I just read a little more code of the ImageTool Component. I thought it was a component in CakePHP meanings which implies putting the file in `/APP/Controller/Component/SomeComponentNameComponent.php` (in your case `ImageToolComponent`) and requesting it in `$components` property of controller (component class has to extends `Component`). So you're right putting it in vendor and call it statically. Think this will not throw any errors. Sorry again, thought it was a "real" CakePHP component.

Comment: your tip was very, very helpful to me!

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it was useful or mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problems. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got all the usage and config info in my repo, some improvements applied!

https://bitbucket.org/gestudio/cakephp-2-imagetoolcomponent

**Examples**

First include the class:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'ImageTool');
```

Make thumbnail 100x100px in size

```
$status = ImageTool::resize(array(
    'input' => $input_file,
    'output' => $output_file,
    'width' => 100,
    'height' => 100
));
```

Resize image (while keeping ratio) with max width and height both set to 600px. After that place watermark image in bottom-right corner and sharpen end result (with default settings)

```
$status = ImageTool::resize(array(
    'input' => $input_file,
    'output' => $output_file,
    'width' => 600,
    'height' => 600,
    'keepRatio' => true,
    'paddings' => false,
    'afterCallbacks' => array(
        array('watermark', array('watermark' => $watermark_file, 'position' => 'bottom-right')),
        array('unsharpMask'),
    )
));
```

Autorotate image (getting back GD resource and then passing it to the next function (greyscale) - similar to previous example but without using afterCallbacks option)

```
$image = ImageTool::autorotate(array(
    'input' => $input_file,
    'output' => null
));

if ($image) {
    $status = ImageTool::grayscale(array(
        'input' => $image,
        'output' => $output_file
    ));
} else {
    $status = false;
}
```